# Como actualizar una tabla a traves de un procedimiento, dependiendo del valor de otra tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito actualizar una tabla mediante un procedimiento dependiendo del valor de otra tabla.

Tengo una tabla "registro" y otra tabla "suscripción" donde en la tabla registro se almacena el usuario y si pago o no el mes. En la tabla suscripción se almacena el usuario, el plan que tiene y si esta activo.
Mediante un procedimiento tengo que actualizar los valores de la tabla suscripcion en la parte si esta activo o no el plan, utilizando los valores si pago o no
S[image: Esta es la tabla registro]

[image: Esta es la tabla suscripcion]

Answer (score 0):

Usa `Merge into`:

```sql
select * 
into #pago_mes
from (
values('Mateo',1), ('Tomas',1),('Alejo',0),('Valentino',0)
  )x(NombreUsuario,PagoMes)

select * 
into #suscripciones
from (
values('Alejo',2,1),('Mateo',1,1),('Tomas',3,1),('Valentino',2,1)
  )x(NombreUsuario,PlanId,Estado)

select * 
from #pago_mes

select * 
from #suscripciones
  
merge into #suscripciones destino
using #pago_mes source
on destino.NombreUsuario = source.NombreUsuario
when matched
then update
set destino.Estado = iif(source.PagoMes=1,1,0); 

select * 
from #suscripciones
```

##### Resultado:

[image: Resultado]